# SWING JPanel / JXPanel Animation

Tags: swing, animation, jpanel

In SWING is there a good/easy way of animating a the show and hide of a JPanel?  I would like animate the expand of a JPanel height.  I figured I could use a timer and increment the height, but was hoping there was something already out there.

Here is an example: (I know this is a web app.... sry). Click Login at the top.
http://web-kreation.com/demos/Sliding_login_panel_jquery/#

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) comes with a JXCollapsiblePanel which might be helpful. Its [demo](http://swinglabs-demos.java.net/demos/swingxset6/swingxset.jnlp) shows it in action (as taskPanes) at the left - that's the part for choosing the demos.

Answer (score 1):

**I would recommend [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home) animation framework.** I will simplify proper animation based on the properties of your panel

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the TimingFramework: http://java.net/projects/timingframework/

It was written by some of the guys from the Swing team before the left a few years ago.

If you really want to look into this in some detail I would recommend picking up Filthy Rich Clients by Chet Hausse and Romain Guy. It's the definitive book about how to do fancy things in a Swing app.